# PHP how to use OR in the right way

Tags: php, laravel, syntax-error

I have simple part of code to detect type of Discount, i added another type, but how to use operator `OR` (`||`) right way in this case ? `->where('taken', "N")` or `"R"` do something.
this wont work `->where('taken', "N" || "R")`

```
$code = Discount::where('code',$discount_code)
        ->where('expiry','>',Carbon::now()->toDateString())
        ->where('subscription', $subscription)
        ->where('taken', "N")
        ->first();
```

Comment: so you want where `'taken'` can be `'N'` or `'R'` ?   this is what `whereIn` is for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in this case use `whereIn()` and pass array to second parameter

`-where('taken', "N" || "R")`

to

`whereIn('taken', ["N","R"])`

so your final code will be

```php
$code = Discount::where('code',$discount_code)
        ->where('expiry','>',Carbon::now()->toDateString())
        ->where('subscription', $subscription)
        ->whereIn('taken', ["N","R"])
        ->first();
```

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#where-clauses

Answer (score 1):

You can use another feature of `->where`, that is that it accepts a callback, that will generate a "nested" function:

```
Discount::where('code',$discount_code)
    ->where('expiry','>',Carbon::now()->toDateString())
    ->where('subscription', $subscription)
    ->where(function($q) use($abc) {
        $q->where('taken', "N")
          ->orWhere('taken', "R");
    })->get();
```

If you are comfortable with SQL, `$q->where('taken', "N")->orWhere('taken', "R");` will be wrapped on `( ... )`, so you will have in SQL

```
WHERE expiry > *a date* AND  subscription = *a value* and (taken = 'N' OR taken = 'R')
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid flakey boolean logic with `expiry > x and taken = N or taken = R`, will will result true if taken is R and ignore expiry. You can give a call back to create parenthesis around your condition.

```
->where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('taken', 'N')
        ->orWhere('taken', 'R');
});
```

This will produce a query similar to this. Which should give the expected result.

```
expiry > x and (taken = N or taken = R)
```

Answer (score 0):

orWhere method can be used

```
    $code = Discount::where('code',$discount_code)
    ->where('expiry','>',Carbon::now()->toDateString())
    ->where('subscription', $subscription)
    ->where('taken', "N")
    ->orWhere('taken', "R")
    ->first();
```